# If a ring R has one sided divisor of zero then show that the R has a both sided divisor of zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If a ring R has one sided divisor of zero then show that the R has a both sided divisor of zero.

If $a(\neq 0)$ is a left divisor of zero, then there exists a $b(\neq 0)\in R$, such that $ab=0$. But how to show that R has a both sided divisor of zero?

Comment: If $ba=0$, then take $a$, else take $ba$.

Comment: @KeithKearnes, in case you make it into an answer, I'll be glad to upvote it.

Answer (score 9):

If $ba=0$, then take $a$, else take $ba$.

Answer (score 3):

Let a be a left divisor of zero. Then a is a non-zero element and there exists another non-zero element b such that ab=0
If ba=0, then b is a both sided divisor of zero.

If possible, let ba be non-zero.

Now, ab=0

This implies, (ab).a=(0).a=0

This implies, a.(ba)=0 [Associativity]

This implies, ba is a right divisor of zero since both a and ba are non-zero elements.

Also, ab=0

This implies, b.(ab)=b.(0)=0

This implies, (ba).a=0 [Associativity]

This implies, ba is a left divisor of zero.

Thus, R contains a both sided divisor of zero.