# Let $R$ be a ring without zero divisors then show that all nonzero elements of $R$ have same additive order

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> **Question** Let $R$ be a ring without zero divisors then show that all nonzero elements of $R$ have same additive order.

(*Though In the book the question is asked only for only for commutative ring but, I think we can prove the result for all rings! **Am i correct?***)

**My attempt**:

Let $x, y$ be any two nonzero elements of a ring $R$

**Case(a)**: let $|x|$ (additive order) is infinite and suppose the (contrary) that, $|y|$ is finite say, $|y|=n$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}
0&= (ny)x\\ 
&=(y+\cdots+y\quad\text{(}n\text{ times)})x\\
&=yx+yx+\cdots+yx\quad(\text{(}n\text{ times)})\\
&=y(x+\cdots+x\quad(\text{(}n\text{ times)})\\
&=y(nx)
\end{align*}$$

Since $y≠0$ and $R$ has no zero divisors we must have, $nx=0$ which contradicts the fact that, $|x|$ is infinite.
Thus, our assumption must be wrong! and so we must have $|y|$ is infinite. Thus, we had proved that, if $R$ has atleast one nonzero element of infinite order then every nonzero element of $R$ has infinite order.

**Case(b)**: let $|x|=n, |y|=m$ where $n<m$ then,

$$\begin{align*}
0&= (nx)y
\\ &=(x+\cdots+x\quad\text{(}n\text{ times)})y
\\&=xy+xy+\cdots+xy\quad(\text{(}n\text{ times)})
\\&=x(y+\cdots+y\quad(\text{(}n\text{ times)})
\\&=x(ny)
\end{align*}$$

As $x≠0$ and $R$ has no zero divisors we must have, $ny=0$ which contradicts the fact that, $|y|=m$ (since  $n<m$). Thus, our assumption that $|x|=n, |y|=m$ where $n<m$ is wrong!
So we must have $|x|=|y|$. Thus, if $R$ has atleast one nonzero element of finite additive order then all nonzero element have finite additive order and all of them have same order.

So by case(a) and case(b). We have, If $R$ is a ring without zero divisors then all nonzero elements of $R$ have same additive order.

**Am I correct? Is there are any mistakes in proof?**

Please help.

Comment: The whole proof seems correct to me

Comment: I think what you wrote is fine.

Comment: The problem with non-commutative rings is one of terminology. Consider Hungerford's book. It defines a "zero divisor" to be an element of $R$ that is *both* a left and a right zero divisor. That means that a "ring without zero divisors" *could* contain left zero divisors or right zero divisors, provided it does not contain any element that is *both*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir, i didn't thought that. In that case my proof is wrong? If yes please could you give counterexample and what if ring has no zero divisors at all? ( No left zero divisors, no right zero divisors, no zero divisors) in this case my proof is ok?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: Your proof is fine for commutative rings, and would be fine for a ring that has no one-sided zero divisors. But imagine you have a ring in which there are left zero divisors and right zero divisors, but no two-sided zero divisors. From $y(nx)=0$, $y\neq 0$, you would *not* be able to conclude $nx=0$ (because maybe $y$ is a left zero divisor and $nx$ a right zero divisor, but neither is a two-sided zero divisor... Similar issues would arise in the second case. This argument would be, at best, incomplete.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir, please provide a  counterexample...

Comment: You asked whether your proof works for noncommutative rings. *As it stands*, it does not because you are assuming your nonzero elements cannot be one-sided zero divisors. Whether the statement is true or false for noncommutative rings is immaterial to the simple fact that the argument you provide **does not work** in the context I indicated: a noncommutative ring with one-sided zero divisors but not two-sided zero divisors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir, i got what you are saying. But, i want to see it practically if possible...I mean, an example of non commutative ring which has left zero divisors and right zero divisors but not two sided zero divisors...

Comment: Actually [they don't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987470/if-a-ring-r-has-one-sided-divisor-of-zero-then-show-that-the-r-has-a-both-sided/1987489), but you need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there was some discussion about the noncommutative case in the comments, I thought I may as well include an alternative perspective on things which should work for noncommutative case as well.

The characteristic of a ring $R$ is defined to be $\text{char} R=\inf \{n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}:n\cdot 1_R=1_R\cdot n:=\underbrace{1_R+...1_R}_{n\text{ terms}}=0\}$

(It's not so important for us here but if you don't have zero divisors, the characteristic is a prime number or infinite).

Rather than comparing the additive order of arbitrary pairs of elements in $R$, we will show that the additive order of a nonzero element will be the same as the additive order of $1_R$ (i.e. the characteristic of the ring).

$\underbrace{r+...+r}_{n\text{ terms}}=r(\underbrace{1_R+...1_R}_{n\text{ terms}})=0$ when $n=\text{char} R$. So, the additive order of $r\in R$ is at most $\text{char}R$.

Conversely, if $n$ is the additive order of $r$, the same algebra together with the fact that there are no zero divisors in $R$ tell us the reverse inequality.

i.e. $\underbrace{r+...+r}_{n\text{ terms}}=0\implies r\cdot (\underbrace{1_R+...1_R}_{n\text{ terms}})=0 $ and since $r\neq 0$, $\underbrace{1_R+...1_R}_{n\text{ terms}}=0$ so $\text{char} R$ is at most the additive order of $r\in R$.

Actually since $1_R$ commutes with everything even in the noncommutative case, we only need that there are no left (or right) zero divisors in $R$!

Comment: I wonder, is this true for non-unital rings? Your argument obviously breaks down (you would need to add a unit without adding zero divisors, which would make the argument circular).

Comment: @tomasz Well, it does say let "$R$ be a ring" and not let "$R$ be a rng", so I should assume we can add $1_R$. Even if it isn't I guess if there are other nonzero central elements, this approach still works.

Comment: I'm not complaining about the legitimacy of your answer, I was just curious about what happens in the more general context. Why would you need central elements, though? Suppose $r,s$ are nonzero, then $n(rs)=(nr)s=r(ns)$. It should follow that $nr=0$ iff $ns=0$ (assuming no zero divisors). In fact, this seems to only really require (two-sided) distributivity (and what seems to be a pretty weak form of it at that), not even associativity. It's just that having no zero divisors is a very strong condition, apparently. Am I missing something?

Comment: @tomasz I agree that what you said makes sense but perhaps that's really a comment on the OP's approach. Just ignore my comment about central elements; I think I was considering something about the case of single-sided zero-divisors.